# Facebook authorization dialog can't load in canvas

Tags: javascript, facebook, canvas

I'm adding login with Facebook (PHP SDK) to my canvas app.

When a user opens the page and they are not already authorized, I create the authorization page URL like this:

```
$data['fb_url'] = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                'scope'=>'email, user_friends',
                'redirect_uri'=>'http://domain.com/error/',
                'display'=>'page'
            ));
```

The URL works (I tried by copy-pasting it into my browser). It shows the page where the user needs to give the app the required permissions. That all works fine.

However, I'd like to redirect the user to this URL at this point. This is where problems arise. The browser (just the canvas iframe, actually) redirects to a blank page. Nothing happens. The same is achieved when redirecting with PHP and when redirecting with Javascript on page load.

When, I place a button on the page which the user can click to be taken to the URL, it also opens a bank page in the canvas.

The only way it works is when I open it with `target=_blank` so it opens as a new browser tab. However, in this case I'm left with the open application page.

To sum up, can I open this dialog within the canvas? If not, what is the best  way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the documentation below, you should use `target="_top"` when using the redirect-url approach: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/using-login-with-games#login